# How to add/subtract an integer to an array of integers?

Tags: postgresql

```sql
select
array[100,200,300]-100
```

My expectation was to get `[0,100,200]`.
I got this error:

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer[] - integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 26
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of array functions: `unnest` and `array_agg`:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT array_agg(val-100) as arr FROM unnest(array[100,200,300]) as val;
     arr     
-------------
 {0,100,200}
(1 row)
```